# how to convert GregorianCalender java in php

Tags: java, php

i want to convert this code in php , i tried my best , Please help me

```
 GregorianCalendar localGregorianCalendar = new                                          
 GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+04:00"));
 System.out.println("Date is :" + localGregorianCalendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Your first visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Your second visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Comment: So, you basically want to equivalent code in php? You want to create a date object with given timezone?

Comment: You can't convert the code, you need to find another library for Gregorian Calendar, or write one yourself. This can be helpful http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jdtogregorian.php

Comment: @mike yes i want same equivalent code

Comment: when i run this code in java it give me this result
Fri Sep 13 18:08:49 GMT 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg'); //set to desired timezone

$date = new DateTime();

//convert date to days
$julian_day = juliantojd ($date->format('m'), $date->format('d'), $date->format('Y'));


echo jdtogregorian ($julian_day) . ' ' . $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Please note that I'm not familiar how hours, minutes and seconds are calculated and is there any difference to the Julian values, so I just used Julian values, I assumed they are the same.

Comment: Mon Sep 09 15:17:54 GMT 2013 Can you please explain what is 09 in it ?
This is a result of java code

Comment: I wouldn't really know, I'm not familiar with that java library, I just pointed you to the way to calculate Gregorian date.